# What's the diagnostic of this bottomless extraction

Tags: espresso

I have juste bought a nuova simonelli musica / eureka mignon, and I m making test with a bottomless filter. Here are the pics: [image: tamper stage]
The extraction: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcKlr.jpg
The coffee after extraction: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKaDb.jpg

In the video we clearly see something is wrong. Then, when I check the filter I can see some channels in the coffee but I don't understand why.

I also notice some coffee on the edge, that could make me think tamper has not the good size. But, I use espro 58' the same I used on a Gaggia Classic, so it should be the good size for the musica.

Can you help me bring a diagnostic to improve my espresso please?

Comment: (1) You tamp with so much force that water channels through the sides. But I think this is uncommon. (2) Some residual grounds left on the inner wall of the filter. So, it cannot place completely. Water channels through the coffee grounds and the inner wall of the filter. I think this is common whenever tamping is not even.

Comment: Hi @MTSan for (1), I am using Espro, so I guess the force is calibrated to 30lb. I could I have an even temping... In the first pic, it seems quite even no ? How should I get rid of residual grounds on the inner wall of the filter ?

Comment: Just hit the basket a few times before tamping to collect the grounds in the middle, than tamp. Afterwards, inspect the walls to see if there are any residues left stuck on the walls. If they are, simply remove them with the tip of your finger. A clean surface may help. The tampers are just a bit smaller in diameter than baskets. This little difference may cause blade thin stuck coffee on the basket walls.

Comment: You need to replace your gasket. You have water leaks.